# How do I use Google Fonts in a HTML page

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I have seen people use Google Fonts within their websites. How do I use Google Fonts within my website? I am using normal fonts such as Arial and Verdana but i want to use Source Sans Pro and Ubuntu fonts as well. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Visit Google Fonts, choose the fonts you want and add the CSS or JavaScript code within your website (depending on what you choose).

Answer (score 2):

1)go to https://www.google.com/fonts#

2) search the font names in the box on top left corner

3) click on add to collection

4) click use

5) select the font weights

6) copy the link tag populated below that and insert it into the `<head>` section of your website

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding